# Command 'ping' is not found using cogs. discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found.
How to fix it?

Main class:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents
import os

intents = Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We Have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

My cog:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class MainCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('pong')     

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MainCog(bot))
```

Comment: what version of discord.py are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, as the other comment mentioned, your Cog class is not inheriting from `commands.Cog`.

Second, you're loading extensions the old way. Extension loading is now asynchronous. This page in the migration guide explains how to do it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Lastly, you have a random `on_message` method floating around in that class. This won't actually do anything. You should attach a listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your class isn't inheriting `commands.Cog`

Changing `class MainCog:` to `class MainCog(commands.Cog):` should fix that problem for you.

Comment: No, it is not working.